# Controlling the speed in ExoPlayer via MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat

How can I control the speed from an exo player via the UI to MediaBrowserServiceCompat?

Does Android provide a normal solution for it?

Comment: your question is vague. Provide some code samples and more insights to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did it like this.

In the activity I did this:

```
MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(ChatActivity.this).sendCommand("speed",bundle,new ResultReceiver(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))
```

And in the MediaBrowserServiceCompat I did it like this:

```
private MediaSessionConnector.QueueEditor getQueueEditor() {
    return new MediaSessionConnector.QueueEditor() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCommand(Player player, String command, @Nullable Bundle extras, @Nullable ResultReceiver cb) {
            float speed = extras.getFloat("SpeedProgress");
            PlaybackParameters param = new PlaybackParameters(speed);
            player.setPlaybackParameters(param);
            player.setPlaybackSpeed(speed);
            return false;
        }
```